# Proving that the set of all real-valued functions is infinite dimensional without the typical infinite dimensional subspace argument

Tags: linear-algebra

The proof that the set of all real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$, denoted $F(\mathbb{R})$, is infinite dimensional usually follows from showing that it has an infinite dimensional subspace (in particular, the space of all polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$ -- incidentally, does this argument rely on deeper results from algebra, that say $x^{n+1}$ cannot be written as a linear combination of polynomials of degree $n$ or lower?). I'm trying to prove this simple statement without appealing to that (just because of how the textbook I'm reading presents things) and I can't seem to do it.
As (I think) is standard, the textbook defines a vector space as being finite dimensional if it equals the span of some finite set. I therefore sought to prove the result as follows:

1. Let $A = \{{f_1,...,f_n}\}$ be a finite subset of $F(\mathbb{R})$, and suppose for the sake of contradiction that every $f \in F(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as a linear combination of these elements of $A$.
2. Construct a $f$ such that this is not true.

I just can't come up with the appropriate construction. From prior experience I know it should be some variant on an arbitrary linear combo of elements of $A$, but I just can't quite think of one.

Comment: I wanted to note that the "proof by contradicion" is unnnecesary. The hypothesis that $A$ spans $F(\mathbb R)$ is there only because you want to contradict it at the end.

It is a tiny bit more elegant to turn your argument into a direct proof of the statement:

"Any finite set $A$ spans a proper subspace of $F(\mathbb R)$"

Then the fact that $F(\mathbb R)$ is of infinite dimension is a simple corollary.

Comment: Thank you, you are very right. I find myself too often bringing out the hammer that is proof by contradiction, even when a more deft touch would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the vector space $F(\Bbb{R}) = \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is isomorphic to its subspace $$P = \{f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} \mid \forall x \le 0.f(x) = 0\}$$ using your favourite bijection between $\Bbb{R}_{>0}$ and $\Bbb{R}$ (e.g. the logarithm function) to translate functions on all reals to functions on positive reals. Clearly $P$ is a proper subspace of $F$, but no finite-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to a proper subspace of itself, so $F(\Bbb{R})$ cannot be finite-dimensional. I leave it to you to translate this into a construction of the sort that you are looking for.

There is nothing special about the reals here: if $X$ is any infinite set and $\Bbb{F}$ is any field, using an injection of $X$ into a proper subset $Y$ of $X$ that is equipollent to $X$, we get an isomorphism of $X \to \Bbb{F}$ with $Y \to \Bbb{F}$ showing that $X \to \Bbb{F}$ is not finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

I can attempt to find a solution along your strategy like this: suppose you have $f_1, \dots, f_n$ a familly of real functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and denote $V$ the span of these vectors. Then I will look at values of functions of $V$ on the integers $0, \dots, n$.

The application $G:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ defined by $G(f) = (f(0), \dots, f(n))$ is linear. $V$ is a finite dimensional space of dimension smaller than $n$ (because it is spanned by $f_1, \dots f_n$). So $G(V)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of dimension smaller than $n$, in particular it is not the whole space. This means that it exists $(a_0, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that no function of $V$ takes exactly the values $f(i) = a_i$ for every integer $i$ between $0$ and $n$.

So to find a function $f$ not in the span $V$ of $f_1, \dots, f_n$, you just have to find a function on $\mathbb{R}$ that takes precisely the values $a_i$ on $i$, and I think you can imagine how to do that.

Comment: Thanks very much. Two quick comments just to confirm: 1) when you say smaller than, you mean that inclusively right ($dim V \leq n$)? 2) when saying $dim G(V) \leq n$, we are appealing to something like the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: Yes I mean $\leqslant$ when I say smaller than. And I don't really think about rank-nullity theorem (even if it works). I mean if $V$ is spanned by $n$ vectors, then $G(V)$ is spanned by the image of these vectors and so G(V) is of dimension $\leqslant n$.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this via diagonalization.

Suppose we have functions $f_1,...,f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Fix some bijection $b:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the following function:

$$g(s)=1+b(s)\cdot\langle f_1(s),...,f_n(s)\rangle.$$

*(here I'm thinking of $b(s)$ as a vector, and "$\cdot$" is the dot product.)*

For any tuple $r_1,...,r_n$ of reals, we have $$g\not=\sum_{i=1}^nr_if_i$$ since in particular we have $$g(b^{-1}(r_1,...,r_n))\not=\sum_{i=1}^nr_if_i(b^{-1}(r_1,...,r_n)).$$ Note that this inequality is guaranteed by the "$1+$" in the definition of $g$; think by analogy of the standard diagonal argument.

It's separately worth noting that this argument also shows that $F(\mathbb{R})$ has *uncountable* dimension: since $\vert\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\vert=\vert\mathbb{R}\vert$ so we can run the same argument. Moreover, everything here is completely constructive, in the sense that given a finite (or countable) subset of $F(\mathbb{R})$ we explicitly produce an element of $F(\mathbb{R})$ not in the span of that set.